# Java Spring lower() has type STRING, but argument is of type java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I created a custom query with jpql in the JPA Repository class. The query will simply return a list as DocumentDTO if the documentText column contains :text. For this operation, I need to perform lowercase operation.

Code:

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.hakstudio.archiveapp.dto.DocumentDTO" +
            "(id, name, accessAuth, uploadedDate, uploadedBy, uploadedByTc, editedBy, editedByTc) " +
            "FROM Document " +
            "WHERE LOWER(documentText) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(:text), '%')")
    List<DocumentDTO> findByDocument(@Param("text") String text);
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Parameter 1 of function lower() has type STRING, but argument is of type java.lang.String
```

I couldn't find how to convert the java.lang.string type to string. Should I do this? Please help me. I couldn't solve the error for 2 days.

I tried this code but I didn't get any results.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.hakstudio.archiveapp.dto.DocumentDTO" +
        "(id, name, accessAuth, uploadedDate, uploadedBy, uploadedByTc, editedBy, editedByTc) " +
        "FROM Document " +
        "WHERE LOWER(documentText as string) LIKE CONCAT('%'," +
        "LOWER(:text as string)" +
        ",'%')")
List<DocumentDTO> findByDocument(@Param("text") String text);
```

Comment: Have you simply tried `LOWER(:text)`

Comment: @Jens Unfortunately, it gave the same error again.

Comment: ... and `LOWER(':text')`? A [MRE] e.g. in form of a github repository would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Turing85 What is the missing information in the question I asked? I can add them if you specify.

Comment: Why not convert "text" to lower case before calling the findByDocument method?

Comment: @HAK Everything except for the code you provided is missing. The whole project structure (incl. the entity-classes, `pom.xml`), the table-definition, and ideally a docker-container for the database, initialized with some test data.

Comment: @Dhanuesh In this way, I eliminate case sensitivity when querying.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. [Here is a `gist.github.com`](https://gist.github.com/turing85/f27590e79a88226ef2cc4bb3fe08c5cb) of my setup. A `curl localhost:8080/names/JOHN` yields `[{"id":1,"name":"John Wayne"},{"id":4,"name":"John Wayne"}]` - just as expected.

Comment: I have similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782114

Answer (score 0):

convert string argument 'text' to lowercase before calling the findByDocument method

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error this way.

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.hakstudio.archiveapp.dto.DocumentDTO" +
        "(id, name, accessAuth, uploadedDate, uploadedBy, uploadedByTc, editedBy, editedByTc) " +
        "FROM Document " +
        "WHERE LOWER(" +
        "cast(documentText as string)" +
        ") LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(" +
        "cast(:text as string)" +
        "), '%')")
List<DocumentDTO> findByDocument(@Param("text") String text);
```