# Hibernate 6.3 CriteriaBuilder.lower() InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException with @Lob annotation

Tags: criteria-api, java-17, spring-boot-3, jakarta-migration, hibernate-6.x

I migrate Spring Boot 2 to version 3. I use Hibernate 6.3.1 Final, Java 17.

After migration, my criteria queries throw InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException.

```java
@Entity
public class FooEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private String comment;

    ...
}
```

```java
    public List<FooEntity> search(FooFilters filters) {
        Specification<FooEntity> specification = getSpecification(filters);
        return fooRepository.findAll(specification);
    }

    private Specification<FooEntity> getSpecification(FooFilters filters) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> p = new ArrayList<>();

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(filters.comment())) {
                p.add(criteriaBuilder.like(
                        criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(FooEntity_.COMMENT)),
                        "%" + filters.comment() + "%"));
            }

            return criteriaBuilder.and(p.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        };
    }
```

Foo is entity with comment field which is String annotated as **@Lob**. Tests are run on h2 database. **I rerun test without @Lob annotation and it works fine.**

I receive exception:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Parameter 1 of function 'lower()' has type 'STRING', but argument is of type 'java.lang.String'
```

Whole example: https://github.com/dcwik96/SpringBoot3LobException

Comment: What is referring `root.get(Foo_.COMMENT)` ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens i updated description. Do you need anything else?

Comment: Thanks. Could you give more class context ?

Comment: I added github repo. It seems that @Lob annotation is reason of this exception

Answer (score 1):

`root.get(FooEntity_.COMMENT)` is returning a "BASIC" type which is backed to STRING in hibernate from what I've seen with your example.

A quickfix would be to add specific cast to `java.lang.String` like this :

`root.get(FooEntity_.COMMENT).as(String.class)`

By doing so, you're code runs without a problem.

Maybe their is a better solution but this one is working. Maybe some information about `@Lob` changes in Hibernate's CHANGELOG can be found between your previous version (in SB2) and the new one (which is the latest in SB3).

Comment: Maybe this is linked to the issue you encounter : [HHH-14605](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14605)